# Escaping colons in filenames in a Makefile

Tags: unix, makefile, gnu-make

Is there a way to get GNU make to work correctly with filenames that contain colons?

The specific problem I'm running into happens to involve a pattern rule.  Here's a simplified version that does not depend on cutting and pasting tab characters:

```
% make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
% cat Makefile
COLON := \:
all: ; true
%.bar: ; cp $< $@
x.bar: x.foo
%.foo: ; touch $@
a$(COLON)b.bar: a$(COLON)b.foo
all: x.bar a$(COLON)b.bar
clean: ; rm -f *.foo *.bar
% make clean
rm -f *.foo *.bar
% make
touch x.foo
cp x.foo x.bar
cp  a\:b.bar
cp: missing destination file operand after `a:b.bar'
Try `cp --help' for more information.
make: *** [a\:b.bar] Error 1
```

Replacing $(COLON) with a literal : produces exactly the same result.  Without the backslash, it does this:

```
Makefile:6: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answers here all seemed too complex to be helpful. I finally found a solution [here](https://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/gnu-make-escaping-walk-wild-side):

```
colon := :
$(colon) := :
```

and then used the macro in the filename as:

```
filename$(:)
```

which successfully translated to "filename:" upon evaluation.

Comment: This does not work in target or prerequisite paths.

Comment: This uses the colon in variable names, which is a nice trick, but doesn't solve the question.

Answer (score 15):

I doubt it's possible: see [this discussion about colons in Makefiles](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-make/2004-10/msg00010.html).  In summary, GNU make has never worked well with filenames that contain whitespace or colons.  The maintainer, Paul D. Smith, says that adding support for escaping would tend to [break existing makefiles](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-make/2004-06/msg00146.html).  Furthermore, adding such support would require significant changes to the code.

You might be able to work around with some sort of nasty temporary file arrangement.

Good luck!

Comment: good find. That's what I was afraid of when I said I was not positive it should work!

Comment: Wow! that's no fun. Make is integral to my workflow. I'm bummed that this isn't possible

Comment: I don't know if GNU Make changed since 2010 (it probably did), but with current GNU Make of 2023, it's as simple as escaping the colon with `\:`.

Answer (score 2):

The following hack worked for me, though it unfortunately relies on $(shell).

```
# modify file names immediately
PRE := $(shell rename : @COLON@ *)
# example variables that I need
XDLS = $(wildcard *.xdl)
YYYS = $(patsubst %.xdl,%.yyy,$(XDLS))
# restore file names later
POST = $(shell rename @COLON@ : *)

wrapper: $(YYYS)
    @# restore file names
    $(POST)

$(YYYS):
    @# show file names after $(PRE) renaming but before $(POST) renaming
    @ls
```

Because PRE is assigned with :=, its associated shell command is run before the XDLS variable is evaluated.  The key is to then put the colons back in place after the fact by explicitly invoking $(POST).

Comment: Pretty good hack!  I am fine with $(shell), my question was specific to GNU make anyway.  I guess this would be an example of a "nasty temporary file arrangement" the other answer was talking about.  I do worry a little about what happens in the case where the thing that "ls" is a placeholder for fails and $(POST) thus doesn't run.  I mean I guess it's probably mostly OK because $(PRE) is idempotent, right?  And if you might have actual @COLON@s in your file names, you just use an even longer and more ridiculous placeholder, maybe with a long random string embedded in it....

Comment: What's this `rename` command?  I don't have it.  `/bin/sh: 1: rename: not found`

Answer (score 1):

There is another way i've found today when dealing with Makefile variables defining filenames (containing colons).

```
# definition
SOME_FNAME = $(NAME)__colon__$(VERSION)

# usage in target
foo:
    $(do_something) $(subst __colon__,:,$(SOME_FNAME))
```

Comment: You don't need to escape filenames used in a recipe.  The following works: `echo bar >:`,
`echo 'all: ; @cat :' >Makefile`, then running `make` prints `bar`, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am not positivie this should work, but the reason it says "missing destination file" is simple:

```
%.bar: ; cp $< $@
```

That line says to copy the target from the *first* dependency. your a:b.bar does not have *any* dependency, so the cp fails. what did you want it to copy ? a:b.foo ? in that case, you would need:

```
%.bar: %.foo ; cp $< $@
```

Comment: The general rule has no dependencies, but I supply a first dependency for two specific cases in subsequent rules.  Yeah, I didn't realize you could do that either, but it turns out you can.  You'll notice it's able to figure out how to create x.bar from x.foo just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the colon with `\:`, as you did, should work.  The only problem is that it you can't second-expand (read about `.SECONDEXPANSION:`) variables with such an escaped semicolon, or the semicolon will stay in the pathname.

Here's some test that works with a simple Makefile:

```bash
$ tree
.
├── Makefile
├── dst
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   └── c
└── src
    └── :

6 directories, 2 files
```

`$ cat Makefile`

```
SRC := $(shell find src -type f | sed 's,:,\\:,')
DST_a := $(patsubst src/%,dst/a/%,$(SRC))
DST_b := $(patsubst src/%,dst/b/%,$(SRC))
DST_c := $(patsubst src/%,dst/c/%,$(SRC))

.PHONY: a
a: $(DST_a);

$(DST_a): $(SRC)
    touch $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:

.PHONY: b
b: $(DST_b);

$(DST_b): $(SRC)
    touch $@

.PHONY: c
c: $(DST_c);

$(DST_c): $$(SRC)
    touch $@
```

```bash
$ make a
touch dst/a/:
```

```bash
$ make b
touch dst/b/:
```

```bash
$ make c
make: *** No rule to make target 'src/\:', needed by 'dst/c/:'.  Stop.
```

```bash
$ tree
.
├── Makefile
├── dst
│   ├── a
│   │   └── :
│   ├── b
│   │   └── :
│   └── c
└── src
    └── :

6 directories, 4 files
```

Another feature that interacts with these is `$(wildcard ...)`.  It unescapes the colons, so you may need to escape again after it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
colon = :
C$(colon)/temp/foo: C$(colon)/temp/bar
    cp $^ $@
```

Answer (score -1):

I could not get the answer posted by @navjotk to work, so I am just gonna cheat and do this;

```
FILENAME:=foo:bar
foo_bar:
    touch $(FILENAME)

run:
    if [ ! -e "$(FILENAME)" ]; then $(MAKE) foo_bar; fi
```

output:

```
$ make run
if [ ! -e "foo:bar" ]; then /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make foo_bar; fi
touch foo:bar

$ ls
Makefile foo:bar
```

Close enough for me.

Comment: A problem with it is that it can't compare timestamps.  If you run make again, it will run again, since it will never find the target, unless you create a dummy file with that name.

Comment: then do not put timestamps in your filename, or find a different solution. I did not write this answer to address the issue of timestamps, I wrote it because I had files with static names that were coming in with `:` due to embedded version tags

Comment: I don't mean timestamps in the filename.  I mean that make normally comprates the 'mtime' of files to decide whether a target is outdated or not.  In your case, the recipe will always be run, as if it were a shell script.  You're not really using make(1) as it's intended to be used.