# Insert time stamp into executable name using makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a simple make file and I want to insert the current date and time into the executable it creates.

Something like: `NOW=$(date +"%c")` to be appended to the exe name. What is the best way to do it?

thanks!

Comment: Which `make`?  (I know how to do this with `gmake`, but I'm far from sure that it can be done with just any make.)

Comment: I am using the default make on Mac OS X. There is no gmake here :(

Comment: Do you want the date to be part of the created file name, or perhaps compiled into the executable. In the later case which programming language is it written in?

Comment: I want the date to be part of the created file name. The programming language is C++. So if the name of the exe is 'test'. I want it to be something like 'test_current_date and time'

Comment: How about composing the date-and-time string using [`date`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html) and then use `mv` to change the executable's file name?

Comment: That would work, how do I accomplish that within a makefile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose you already have a `Makefile` which creates application. So here's something you might add:

```
# Use ':=' instead of '=' to avoid multiple evaluation of NOW.
# Substitute problematic characters with underscore using tr,
#   make doesn't like spaces and ':' in filenames.
NOW := $(shell date +"%c" | tr ' :' '__')

# Main target - your app + "date"
all: foo_$(NOW)

# Normal taget for your app which already have.
foo: foo.cpp

# Copy "normal" app to app_DATE
# You'll rater want copy then move, otherwise make will have
#   to link your app again during each execution (unless that's
#   exactly what you want).
foo_$(NOW): foo
    cp $^ $@
```

Notice the replacement of `':'` with `'_'`. As indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2052576/703503) if date contains a colon make will probably fail to parse the Makefile.

I have no access to Mac OS X at the moment, so this was only tested on Ubuntu, but I used to work on an Mac machine once and I didn't notice any significant differences in `make`. So it should work for you too.

**--- edit ---**

As Beta rightly commented, the method described above creates new copy with current date every time `make` is called. It might be desired sometimes, so I'll leave it be, and propose following alternative for situations when it's not:

```
# Same as above...
NOW := $(shell date +"%c" | tr ' :' '__')

# Default target
all: foo  # <-- not foo_$(NOW) anymore, foo_$(NOW) target is removed altogether

OBJ := foo.o bar.o  # other ...

# Normal taget for your app which already have, but...
foo: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
    cp $@ $@_$(NOW)  # <-- additional copy at the end (read on below)
```

Why is `foo_$(NOW)` target gone? Because you *only* want to create a date-stampped copy of the app *if* you modified the app itself. Which means you can't create a target, because then `make` would *always* create the copy (as in above scenario).

This however means that `make` is unaware of existence of the copy. The copy is not present in the dependency graph that `make` creates upon startup. So the copy can't be used as a prerequisite to any other target. It's not a disadvantage, but direct result of the fact that we don't know upfront if we're going to create the copy or not. (If someone has a way to overcome this without running secondary make run, please indulge me :) ).

Comment: +1, but one caveat: this will produce a new executable every time it runs, regardless of whether the source has changed...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is almost perfect except as Beta noted, I do end up recompiling all the files everytime even though the sources have not changed. Is there any way around it?

Comment: @Beta - yes, I thought such were the requirements. user308827 - you shouldn't be recompiling **all** the files, but only those that have changed since last run. This is true even with my first proposal. If you do end up compiling everything every time then there are surely some undesired dependencies in your Makefile. Anyway take a look at the edit I made.