# How to use variable with ':' in a Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I got a problem when I want to use make, containing a variable linking to my folder.

Like this :

```
DIR_ST = I\ \:\ The\ Scared\ Stones

SRC_ST = $(DIR_ST)/main.c

OBJ_ST = $(SRC_ST:.c=.o)
```

But when I want to compile like this:

```
all : $(ST)
$(ST) : $(OBJ_ST)
$(CC) $(OBJ_ST) -o strategic
```

i got this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `I \: The Sacred Stones/main.o', needed by `binaries/strategic'.  Stop.
```

How can I use this folder's name in a Makefile?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052406/escaping-colons-in-filenames-in-a-makefile

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could place a symbolic link in the current directory to the 'I:\ The Scared Stones directory

suggest using a link name that does not have any spaces